# Why does dyld look for dynamic libraries in the process's current working directory at runtime?

Tags: linker, ld, dyld

Say when compiling my executable, I link it with a custom library.
`gcc -c main.c -lcustom -o exec`

Then when I go to run my executable, if my process's current working directory contains libcustom.dylib, then execution will work, otherwise it won't.
When I read the man pages for dyld, it seems like it does not consider the current working directory of the process to be a runtime path.